# the Html and the soup result is way different

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having some difficulties with Beautifulsoup.

You can find the html here -> http://pastebin.com/Nr1k0dcM

after that I simply run a `soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.prettify()`

There shouldn't be any difference in the result from the html but I only get this > http://pastebin.com/Y6DmEj40

I really don't understant what's going on here...

EDIT:

This is one of the url I'm scrapping for example: http://fantasy.premierleague.com/entry/38861/event-history/8/

I'm only scrapping the html from  to  because otherwise I'm getting an the following error:

`HTMLParser.HTMLParseError: bad end tag: u"</scri'+'pt>", at line 89, column 222`

So what I'm doing right now is the following

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
html = response.text
tablestart = html.find('<!-- pitch view -->') + 19
tableend = html.find('<!-- end ismPitch -->')
html = html[tablestart:tableend]
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Comment: Would you mind giving us the website you are scraping? The issue might simply be that it is redirecting you to another website (say a Mobile one) and hence the different html code

Comment: I've added an edit to my original post for you Madawar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement your above code in this manner

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://fantasy.premierleague.com/entry/38861/event-history/8/")
html = response.read()
tablestart = html.find('<!-- pitch view -->') + 19
print tablestart
tableend = html.find('<!-- end ismPitch -->')
print tableend
html = html[tablestart:tableend]
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Output of the above code is

```
55594
92366
```

Comment: This is what I'm already doing. I'm just using Requests and not urllib2. For what it is worth, I tried it with urllib2 and it's not working either :(

Comment: I have just tested the above code and it works, am not sure what might be your problem

Comment: What's your output for print soup.prettify() ?

Comment: I don't get the same result when I run your code.

This is what I get: http://pastebin.com/9hGH5a0q